# JavaMail does not respond only when invoked from webapp

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-mail

I have JavaMail up and running, I can send emails and it works seamlessly. It usually takes 2-3 seconds to establish the connection and send the email. The problem is that  when I call the same method by clicking a submit button in a .jsp page that is linked to the Controller using @RequestMapping the email does not get sent at all, the page just keeps on waiting the method to finish running, but it never finishes it's like an infinite loop.

I've created the EmailUtil.java even as a thread and ran it but the results where the same.

Here is the code.

I use this class to send emails:

```
''''
    public class EmailUtil {
    
    /**
     * Utility method to send simple HTML email
     * @param session
     * @param toEmail
     * @param subject
     * @param body
     */
    
    private static final String ABSOLUTE_PATH = "(path to my email and password - ignore this) -credentials.properties";
    
    public static void prepareEmail(Session session, String toEmail, String subject, String body){
        try
        {
            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    
            //set message headers
            msg.addHeader("Content-type", "text/HTML; charset=UTF-8");
    
            msg.addHeader("format", "flowed");
    
            msg.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "8bit");
    
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("no_reply@example.com", "NoReply-MVC"));
    
            msg.setReplyTo(InternetAddress.parse("no_reply@example.com", false));
    
            msg.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
    
            msg.setText(body, "UTF-8");
    
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());
    
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(toEmail, false));
    
            System.out.println("Message is ready");
    
            Transport.send(msg);
    
            System.out.println("EMail Sent Successfully!!");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    enter code here
    public static void sendEmail(String toEmail, String code){
    
     String email =  null; //requires valid gmail id
     String password = null;
    
     try{
         FileReader reader=new FileReader(ABSOLUTE_PATH);
    
         Properties p=new Properties();
    
         p.load(reader);
    
         email = p.getProperty("email");
    
         password = p.getProperty("password");
    
     }catch (IOException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.out.println("Error geting email + password");
     }
     System.out.println("TLSEmail Start");
    
     Properties props = new Properties();
    
     props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); //SMTP Host
    
     props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); //TLS Port
    
     props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); //enable authentication
    
     props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); //enable STARTTLS
    
        //create Authenticator object to pass in Session.getInstance argument
    
     final String EMAIL = AES.decrypt(email);
    
     final String PASSWORD = AES.decrypt(password);
    
     Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
         //override the getPasswordAuthentication method
         protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
             return new PasswordAuthentication(EMAIL, PASSWORD);
         }
     };
     Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
     EmailUtil.prepareEmail(session, toEmail,"This is your confirmation code:", code);
    }
    }
''''

''''

This is the method that is invoked from the .jsp page:

    @RequestMapping("enterCode")
    public String enterCode(){
        
        EmailUtil.sendEmail(email,"hello there");
    
        System.out.println("CODE: "+code+" ATTEMPTED TO BE SENT TO : "+generalUser.getEmail());
    
        return "verification-form";
    }
''''
```

And this is the .jsp page (not really relevant but I thought to include it anyway):

```
''''
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Login</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Interactive Login Form.">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/main.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nova+Round&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<div class = "container">

    <form:form action = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}editPage" modelAttribute="dbUser">

        <input type="submit" class = "submitButton" id = "editProfileButton" name = "form" value ="Edit Profile">

    </form:form>

    <br><br>
    <form:form action = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}enterCode" modelAttribute="dbUser">

        <input type="submit" class = "submitButton" id = "editProfileButton" name = "form" value ="Verify Email">

    </form:form>
 
</div>

</body>

</html>
''''
```

[image: When invoking the sendEmail() method from anywhere in the IDE]

[image: When invoking the sendEmail() from the .jsp page, just keeps like this forver]

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it perfectly works on google chrome but it still hangs in Safari. I will update the answer if I find a solution for this.